# arduino `shiftOut()` function in native c

Tags: c, arduino, bit

I'm trying to create the equivalent of the arduino `shiftOut()` function in native c on my mcu.

I want to send the command `int gTempCmd  = 0b00000011;` via a `shiftOut()` type function with `MSBFIRST`.

What would the pseudo code for this look like so I can try map it my mcu's gpio functions?

Thanks

```
float readTemperatureRaw()
{
  int val;

  // Command to send to the SHT1x to request Temperature
  int gTempCmd  = 0b00000011;

  sendCommandSHT(gTempCmd);
  ...
  return (val);
}


//Send Command to sensor
void sendCommandSHT(int command)
{
  int ack;

  shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, command);
  ....
}
```

Comment: See https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ShiftOut

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following 'psuedo-c++'

The code works as follows:

- take the highest, or lowest bit in the word by AND-ing with all zero's except the MSB or LSB, depending on the MSBFIRST flag
- write it to the output pin
- shift the command one step in the right direction
- pulse the clock pin
- repeat 8 times, for each bit in the command

It is fairly trivial to expand this to an arbitrary number of bits upto 32 by adding a parameter for the number of repetitions

```
void shiftOut(GPIO dataPin, GPIO clockPin, bool MSBFIRST, uint8_t command)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
   {
       bool output = false;
       if (MSBFIRST)
       {
           output = command & 0b10000000;
           command = command << 1;
       }
       else
       {
           output = command & 0b00000001;
           command = command >> 1;
       }
       writePin(dataPin, output);
       writePin(clockPin, true);
       sleep(1)
       writePin(clockPin, false);
       sleep(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Lundin, changed code to use a function call to set GPIO pins. This will also prevent the compiler from reordering the sleeps and get rid of the first assignment.

Comment: I notice you put two `sleep(1)` functions ... In my related question https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/72074/it-the-shiftout-code-depending-on-the-low-speed-of-an-arduino shows that the original Arduino code does not have this, The answer said because it relies on a rising/falling edge, but is the `sleep(1)` needed ?

Comment: The sleep calls are there to indicate some delay, depending on the desired duration of the pulse. I think that setting the output takes 1 clock tick, so the pulse would only be 62.5 ns without delay. Even a small capacitance on the output would result in no detectable output at all. It /may/ work fine but I doubt it would work reliably, especially over longer wires.